# Can't figure out what is wrong with my rot-13 method

Tags: java, methods, rot13

I've been changing it around a lot. And, it just keeps getting worse. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. From A-M, add 13. From M-Z, subtract 13. Before, at least I was receiving back letters. Now, they symbols.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ExerciseE {

    public static String rot13(String s) {
        char value = 0;
        char position = s.charAt(0);
        String rev = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            position = s.charAt(i); 
            if (position >= 65 && position <= 77) {
                value = (char) (position + 13);
            }
            if (position >= 78 && position <= 90) {
                value = (char) (position - 13);

            } else {
            }
            rev = (rev + value);

        }
        return rev;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a phrase or sentence:");
        s = s.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(rot13(s));     
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding/subtracting from `value` not position...

```
value = (char) (value + 13);
```

Should probably be

```
value = (char) (position + 13);
```

And the same goes for the subtraction

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `position + 13` rather than `value + 13`, and similar for the subtract case.

The bigger picture is that you should never initialize a local variable without knowing why it needs to be initialized. Normally, the compiler will be able to see that every path leading to a use of the variable goes through an assignment. If `value` had not been initialized, the compiler would have warned about its use.